# Speech Kit limits: how do I know that I've reached them?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

I'm using speech recognition in my app. It's guite important for user experience, so I want it to be good (and free or cheap).

Right now, I'm using Speech Kit from Apple, and it works like a charm but it's not very reliable because there are some limits per app and per device, and I don't know these limits.

Another option is to use OpenEars. It's not nearly as good as Speech Kit for me, so I'm thinking about switching from Speech Kit to OpenEars silently if Speech Kit is not working (and back,when Speech Kit is alive and well).

But is there a way to know that Speech Kit is not working right now before ever using it?

The only way I know of is to try to recognise some audiofile before every user session, but it needs time (at least, several seconds will be spent, and several seconds is a lot), and it's not very good solution in terms of using the service — it seems too costly to recognise audio just to check if Speech Kit is working or not. Also, I don't know how to debug this, because obviously I don't have any problems with limits in my app right now.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I also thought about this question not long ago. Here's an answer from the Apple Q & A. "The current rate limit for the number of SFSpeechRecognitionRequest calls a device can make is 1000 requests per hour." There is also an example of the error being received upon reached limit, so you can prepare yourself for that :)

Here's the link: [Apple Q & A](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1951/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017662)